# AutoMapper configuration to use local time for all DateTime properties

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Say I have 2 classes with the same set of properties:

```
public class MyDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map with [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started), adjusting the UTC date of the input class to local time of the output class, e.g., granted I am in UK where UTC offset currently is 1h:

```
var input = new MyDto {Id = 1, CreatedOn = DateTime.Parse("01-01-2015 14:30")};
var output = Mapper.Map<MyViewModel>(input); // output.CreatedOn = "01-01-2015 15:30"
```

Can I cofigure AutoMapper to this automatically for all `DateTime` properties?

N.B. to adjust the time I use `DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Utc)`

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom type converter:

```
public class CustomDateTimeConverter : ITypeConverter<DateTime, DateTime> {
    public DateTime Convert(ResolutionContext context) {
        var inputDate = (DateTime) context.SourceValue;
        var timeInUtc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(inputDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(timeInUtc, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
    }
}
```

This will make AutoMapper perform the conversion from UTC to local time for every mapping between two `DateTime` properties.

Comment: For specific maps, we can use [AfterMap](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html) actions.